# Creating MVC 4 data access layer using SQL Server 2000

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am a novice ASP.Net developer/student/intern. Currently, I am in the process of creating my first MVC web app with:

- VS 2012 Ultimate C#
- SQL Server 2000

My database is on a SQL Server 2000 with no chance of upgrading to >= 2005 in the foreseeable future. Thus preventing me from using EF, which all the books and examples I’ve read so far have used.

I have created a C# SQL helper class for connections, commands etc. that I have used previously as a data access layer for other basic web form applications.

What's the best way to incorporate it into my current MVC DAL?

Also,are there any examples or documentation outlining the basic steps in creating a sound MVC DAL that adheres to MVC best practices while using server 2000 and without EF.?

Any suggestions/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you,
Todd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically speaking, MVC has nothing to do with your DAL. As far as your MVC app is concerned, it shops at the repository layer and does not care what happens in the warehouse (data layer).

Your DAL can be built using ADO.NET. Although this technology is old, its perfectly usable. If you check out http://www.dofactory.com/Default.aspx, you will see an app that is build using multiple DAL technologies. One is for Entity Framework and another is for ADO.Net ... and the cool part is they are BOTH hitting the same database.